# React.js: props.state is blank(null)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to Todo List in use React.js + Redux.

I make reducer file:

```
import { ADD_POST, REMOVE_POST } from "../actions/index.jsx";

const initialState = {
 title: "",
 content: ""
};

export default function Post(state = initialState, action) {
 switch (action.type) {
  case ADD_POST:
   return [
    ...state,
    {
      id: action.id,
      title: action.title,
      content: action.content
    }
  ];
  case REMOVE_POST:
    return state.filter(({ id }) => id !== action.id);
  default:
    return state;
 }
}
```

And, I edit App.js :

```
class App extends Component {
render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Input />
      <List posts={this.props.allPosts} />
  </div>
  );
 }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
 return {
   allPosts: [state.title, state.content]
 };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(App);
```

And, List Component is...:

```
 render() {
   return (
     <div>
       <ul>
         {this.props.posts.map((post, index) => (
         <Item {...post} key={index} />
        ))}
       </ul>
     </div>
   );
  }
 }
```

I am experiencing the error "Can not read property 'map' of undefined" and can not proceed.

How can I fix it?

I'm referring to multiple sources, but I'm having difficulty because I can only see text for one 'text' state, and two sources like 'title' and 'content' states.

-------_FIX

I fix error, but props.state is blank.
I add input tag with texts but it not change everything.

[image]

-------Actions

```
export const ADD_POST = "ADD_POST";
export const REMOVE_POST = "REMOVE_POST";

let nextId = 0;

export function addPost(title, content) {
 return {
   type: ADD_POST,
   id: nextId++,
   title,
   content
 };
}

export function removePost(id) {
 return {
   type: REMOVE_POST,
   id
 };
}
```

Comment: Did you add your `mapStateToProps` function to your component file?

Comment: @BlunderingPhilosopher I add mapStateToProps in App.js

Comment: Can you show your actions?

Comment: @Colin Add actions with post.

Comment: Can you show your List component please?

Comment: @Colin Edit post. check please

Comment: You're returning an array from your `ADD_POST` function, I don't think you want that, you should be returning an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confusing with the data type of your state. The below snippet might work for you. I've kept your state as an array of posts with initialState being an empty array.
So in your reducer file, initialise the initialState as:

```js
import {
  ADD_POST,
  REMOVE_POST
} from "../actions/index.jsx";

const initialState = [];

export default function Post(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_POST:
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          id: action.id,
          title: action.title,
          content: action.content
        }
      ];
    case REMOVE_POST:
      return state.filter(({
        id
      }) => id !== action.id);
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

In App.js, in the function mapStateToProps, map allPosts to state which is an array.

```js
class App extends Component {
render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Input />
      <List posts={this.props.allPosts} />
  </div>
  );
 }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
 return {
   allPosts: state
 };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(App);
```

Comment: I change it, but it occurs error "TypeError: this.props.posts.map is not a function".

Comment: Can you print state in mapStateToProps and tell what you're getting.